# Using Google App Engine's Mail API for django-allauth email

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-allauth

I'm working on a project hosted on Google App Engine, and using Django-allauth for my user system.

Right now I'm just using the following setup in settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myMail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

But I would like to use GAE's Mail API instead, so that I can take use of all the quotas available.

To send an email with GAE's API I can do as follows:

```
sender_address = "myMail@gmail.com"
subject = "Subject"
body = "Body."
user_address = "user@gmail.com"
mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body)
```

As I understand it from the [allauth documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-e-mail), I can "hook up your own custom mechanism by overriding the send_mail method of the account adapter (allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter)."

But I'm really confusing about how to go about doing this.

Does it matter where I place the overridden function?

Any additional tips would be greatly appreciated.

---

**My Solution**

What I did to get Django-allauth email system to work with [Google App Engine mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/)

Created a file auth.py in my 'Home' app:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from google.appengine.api import mail


class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)

        sender_address = "myEmailAddress@gmail.com"
        subject = msg.subject
        body = msg.body
        user_address = email
        mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body)
```

In order to use your email as sender with GAE's mail API, it is important to remember to [authorize the email](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings?_ga=1.188328232.1621371166.1457542141) as a sender

Lastly, as e4c5 pointed out, allauth has to know that this override exists, which  is done as so in settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'home.auth.MyAccountAdapter'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell django-allauth about your custom adapter by adding the following line to settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my_app.MyAccountAdapter'
```

taking care to replace my_app with the correct name

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I'll update the main question for how to extract the useful information to use the send_mail with GAE api's once I've figured it all out.