# Sending email from appengine with django and django-allauth is not working

Tags: django, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, django-allauth

I am using django 1.8.13 with django-allauth 0.25.2 on appengine with google cloud SQL and I cannot send emails.

I have tried using the django EmailBackend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

and also the email backend from djangae, which is actually the same as from django-nonrel (I have copied the code to my project):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'mail.AsyncEmailBackend'
```

With the django backend I get an error:

gaierror at /accounts/signup/ [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

With the djangae backend I get no error but also no email.

I have set the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting to an email in the list of authorized senders from my project.

I am out of ideas of what to do more to find out the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the email host that you are connecting to?

Comment: In my settings I have tried using EMAIL_HOST = '' and EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'

I have another similar project running django 1.5.8 on appengine and with django-nonrel and the EMAIL_HOST is localhost and the emails are sent fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914687/django-sending-email

Comment: You can find the answer here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714106/using-google-app-enignes-mail-api-for-django-allauth-email